# Django-Cookie-Consent walkthrough or tutorial

Tags: django, cookies

I am looking at launching my very first Django app, and would like to implement cookie consent. I am still fairly new to django and programming and I have read through the docs but as this is my first time with a web app and with really dealing with cookies, I am having trouble understanding exactly what to do.

I would just like to find out if anyone knows of a walkthrough or a tutorial implementing django cookie consent? I have it installed but am unsure how exactly to "make it work" how if a user declines a certain cookie I would actually "listen" or implement to their choice?

As well as how to set up cookie groups and cookies themselves.

While the documentation seems clear for an "advanced beginner" it does seem a little hard to know exactly what to do and how to go about it.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: If by any chance you're still trying take a look at the example project they have in the repo: https://github.com/bmihelac/django-cookie-consent/tree/master/tests/core

Comment: Awesome thank you, I will definitely go have a look.

Comment: The link is not working. Im into the same situation did you find any solution? Please let me know.

Comment: The project is being migrated to JazzBand. The new url is: https://github.com/jazzband/django-cookie-consent/tree/master/tests